# Проблемы с pickle. Ошибка: TypeError: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes

Tags: python

Делаю дз в универе(тема работа с файлами, не буду углубляться, скажу лишь, что смысл заключается в создании файла-каталога игрушек с доп. условием поиска в файле определенной игрушки с определенными параметрами, при её отсутствии добавить такую). Сам только разбираюсь в python.

Создал функцию для проверки наличия игрушки:

```
def check(file_name):
file = open(file_name,'rb')
line = p.load(file_name)
file.close()
isGood = True
for g_counter in range(len(line)):
    for l_counter in line[g_counter]:
        if l_counter[0] == "Конструктор" and l_counter[1] == 22 \
            and l_counter[2] == 5 and l_counter[3] == 10:
            pass
        else:
            isGood = False
return isGood
```

В атрибутах p.load() указал 'rb', но python выдает:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/HW/task.py", line 45, in <module>
    if check(file_name) == True:
    File "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/HW/task.py", line 31, in check
    line = p.load(file_name)
    TypeError: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes
```

Анализировал аналогичные задачи-примеры, где синтаксис идентичен, все работает.
Нашел в интернете несколько решений данной проблемы, но ничего не помогло. Возможно я что-то упускаю, но потратив уйму времени на решение, я так и не понял в чем дело.

Для наглядности весь код:

```
    import pickle as p


    def createtoylist(file_name):
    line = []
    for counter in range(int(input("К-ство игрушек:"))):
        name = str(input("Название игрушки: "))
        price = int(input("Цена игрушки: "))
        min_age = int(input("Нижняя возрастная граница: "))
        max_age = int(input("Верхняя возрастная граница: "))
        tup = (name, price, min_age, max_age)
        line.append(tup)
    file = open(file_name, "wb")
    p.dump(line, file)
    file.close()


    def addone(file_name):
    file = open(file_name, "rb")
    line = p.load(file_name)
    file.close()
    toy = ("Конструктор", 22, 5, 10)
    line.append(toy)
    file = open(file_name, 'wb')
    p.dump(line, file)
    file.close()


    def check(file_name):
    file = open(file_name,'rb')
    line = p.load(file_name)
    file.close()
    isGood = True
    for g_counter in range(len(line)):
        for l_counter in line[g_counter]:
            if l_counter[0] == "Конструктор" and l_counter[1] == 22 \
                and l_counter[2] == 5 and l_counter[3] == 10:
                pass
            else:
                isGood = False
    return isGood


    file_name = str(input("Название файла: "))
    createtoylist(file_name)
    if check(file_name) == True:
        print("Игрушка присутствует.")
    else:
        addone(file_name)
        print("Такой игрушки нету, но она добавлена.")
```

Подскажите в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в том что вы передали имя файла (`p.load(file_name)`) вместо объекта `file` (`p.load(file)`)

`pickle.load(file)` в качестве `file` ожидает объект обладающий методом `.read()`. Например объект, возвращаемый функцией `open()`

Для вашего кода:

```
def check(file_name):
    with open(file_name,'rb') as file:
        line = p.load(file)
    # ...
```

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. Очень благодарен.